# problemas com retorno "None" em Python

Tags: python, xml

Olá, estou tentando obter dados de uma API para um trabalho da universidade, porém ao tentar printar os dados obtidos, recebo o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Segue o código utilizado:

```
    def list_all_political_parties():

    base_url = "http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/senador/partidos"

    data = requests.get(url=base_url)
    data_to_dict = xmltodict.parse(data.content)
    data_to_xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(data_to_dict)

    root = elements.fromstring(data_to_xml)
    levels = root.findall('.//Partido')
    for level in levels:
        code = level.find('Codigo').text
        initials = level.find('Sigla').text
        name = level.find('Nome').text
        creation_date = level.find('DataCriacao').text
        print(code, initials, name, creation_date)

list_all_political_parties()
```

Quando eu tento rodar o código sem o atributo "text", o print ocorre como:

> (None, None, None, None)

O esquisito é que um get em http://legis.senado.gov.br/dadosabertos/senador/partidos retorna um xml com diversos dados, sendo assim, acredito que por erro meu, algum dado tem se perdido no retorno.

Alguém poderia me dar um dica sobre como resolver isso?

Desde já agradeço a atenção e ajuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se entendi bem o motivo de você transformar o `xml` em dicionário e depois em `xml` de volta!

De qualquer forma, acho que é mais fácil trabalhar diretamente com o dicionário!

Depois de você criar a variável `data_to_dict` basta executar:

```
for p in data_to_dict['ListaPartidos']['Partidos']['Partido']:
    print(p['Codigo'],p['Sigla'],p['Nome'],p['DataCriacao'])
```

Cheguei nesse código ai investigando o dicionário gerado pelo `xmltodict.parse()`!

Esse print aí tem exatamente os dados que você precisa!

Comment: Olá @weulerfilho, obrigado pela ajuda, realmente era isso que eu precisava, eu fiz a conversão de xml pra dict e depois para xml por vacilo mesmo hehehehe, uma dúvida: é possível remover o "u" que precede cada dado?

Abraços e obrigado